# My custom header and footer works except on the chapter page?

Tags: memoir

I created custom headers and footers using the code below. They work great except they are not applied to the chapter pages--the default footer is used. So, instead of page numbers at the edge, the first page of each chapter has the page number centered? How do I override the chapter page footer and header?

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makepagestyle{mystyle}
\makeevenhead{mystyle}{}{}{}
\makeoddhead{mystyle}{}{}{\itshape\leftmark}
\makeevenfoot{mystyle}{\thepage}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{mystyle}{}{}{\thepage}

\pagestyle{mystyle}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Test Section}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{mystyle}` though I would never have headers on a chapter page. So I'd make a copy of `mystyle` and remove the headers and then alias the `chapter` style to that. See also https://tug.org/pracjourn/2008-2/madsen/madsen.pdf

Comment: mystyle will show the last chapter title on the first page of the chapter.  Try `\def\chaptermark#1{\xdef\leftmark{#1}}`.

Comment: @daleif Thanks! Worked great!

Comment: There is a good reason to avoid what you want to do by default. Do you think that really the reader will need the header orientation in that page, having in front of his nose the huge title of the chapter?  This way you just downplay the title relevance.

Comment: @Fran was never about the header. My issue was the format of the page number in the footer. Adding a header to a chapter page would be redic. daleif's answer was spot on

Comment: @buttonsrtoys Oh, sorry. Reading the title and your last sentence, both referring to the  header too, I overlooked that only the footer bothered you really.